# alternate solution for really big result sets / queries in firebase cloud function using cloud firestore as a database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am programming an app (with Flutter and Firebase) that should give users the option to get a reminder at certain times.

For example, I could set that I would like to be reminded by push notification every day at 3:35 p.m., but only when there is something to do.

For this I have created a cloud function that is called every 5 minutes.

First, the function makes a database query for all users who have set a reminder for the current time.

```
    const snapshot = await firestore.collection('reminders')
        .where('server.time', '==', time)
        .where('server.days', 'array-contains', day).get();
```

The function then checks for each reminder / user who wants a reminder whether there is something to be done. If this is the case, a Firebase Cloud Message is sent to the relevant user.

```
const result = await firestore.collection('tasks').where('date', '==', date)
    .orderBy('created').limit(1).get();
if (result.size === 1) {
    sendMessage();
}
```

I'm afraid that the first database query (with a growing number of active users) will cause me problems. Everything that comes after that, I would try to outsource to individual cloud functions, which could then be processed in parallel (I hope this is possible).

If at some point there are very many users who want to be reminded at the same time, the query will take too long. In the worst case, the messages would be sent several minutes too late or not be sent at all if the query took longer than the function limit of 540 seconds.

I did a few small tests myself to get a first impression of the performance of slightly larger queries.

These are my results with 512MB memory:

- 100 documents = 294 ms
- 1,000 documents = 2205 ms
- 2,000 documents = 1621 ms
- 10,000 documents = 5957 ms
- 20,000 documents = 10687 ms

These are my results with 8GB memory:

- 100 documents = 122 ms
- 1,000 documents = 442 ms
- 2,000 documents = 566 ms
- 10,000 documents = 1932 ms
- 20,000 documents = 3884 ms

The higher memory seems to have a positive effect. Still, I believe 100,000 or even 1,000,000 documents might take several minutes to complete.

I thought that pagination with an offset could be a solution.
Then I would have called a separate cloud function for each batch of, for example, 50,000 documents, which would then make the actual queries and could work in parallel.

Something like:

```
export const sendReminders = firebase.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(async () => {
    const batchSize = 500000;
    const documentCount = 1000000;  // could be saved in the database
    const batchCount = Math.ceil(documentCount / batchSize);
    for (let batch = 0; batch < batchCount; batch++) {
        handleBatch(batchSize, batch * batchSize);
    }
}

async function handleBatch(limit: number, offset: number, date: string) {
    const result = await firestore.collection('reminders').where('date', '==', date)
        .orderBy('created').limit(limit).offset(offset).get();
    for (const document in result.docs) {
        checkReminder(date, document);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, with Firebase you have to pay for all data records from the offset.
So this seems like a very expensive solution. Since the whole problem only exists with large amounts of data.

The size of the documents certainly plays a role in the speed of the queries.
In my case, a document has about 25 relatively small fields with little data. Short Strings for names, Id’s that refer to other documents, a few Booleans, etc.
Nothing really special, not a particularly large amount of data within a document.

Is there any other way I could possibly approach the problem differently?
So that my app or cloud function doesn't get slower as the number of users increases?

Does anyone have any experience of how long very large queries (100,000 to 1,000,000 documents) take with Cloud Firestore?

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Hello, if my answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the tick icon ;) else feel free to ask further queries.

Comment: Make sure to understand [how "every 5 minutes" is interpreted](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#defining_the_cron_job_schedule). If a scheduled function takes longer than 5 minutes, it will start skipping triggers. e.g. If the run at 12:00 takes 7 minutes, the run at 12:05 will be skipped.

Comment: Cloud Firestore is an indexed database, so even with queries that have to search thousands of documents, the query time will be speedy as it only looks up the parts of the index related to your query. Once a query has found the matching documents, the time it takes to download those documents depends entirely on the content of those documents. If your query only needs the document ID or one field from the entire document (like a user ID), consider applying a field mask to your query using the [`select()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#select) method.

Comment: @samthecodingman Thanks for your hints. I didn’t know that triggers could be skipped if the previous one took to long. This will surely save me a few problems. It’s good to know that there is a possibility of limiting the fields with cloud functions. I will definitely implement that. It is pity that this option is not also available with the client SDKs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you perform your tests (and how many times)?

```
100 documents = 294 ms
20,000 documents = 10.687 ms
```

20K documents took less time than 100. I won't question about that because that could be because of cold starts. There could be multiple solutions to this and of course running Cloud function with maximum possible timeout and resources is one of them.

If you still think `540 seconds` is less to process all your data, consider using [Google Cloud Compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute) as it won't have timeout and you can use [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) to periodically run functions on your compute instance.

If you want to stick with Cloud Functions, then a simple strategy would be to divide your reminders in *N* batches i.e. adding a field `{batch: n}`. Then run *N* scheduled functions on the same schedule and each function will look for documents where batch number is equal to the number allotted to them. For example, first function will look for batch 1 and so on.

> How long very large queries (100,000 to 1,000,000 documents) take?

I can't really share any statistics but it also depends on what kind of process you will be running on them and how time consuming that is. I'm not sure if you are referring to download times.

I usually go with 1st method as it has more flexibility and less cold starts (runs all the time with other processes). You can use [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) node package instead of scheduler on a Cloud Compute instance.

Comment: The point should actually be a comma as a thousand separator. (In Germany we use points) That was a mistake, I corrected. So it took 10687 ms to fetch 20000 documents.

There shouldn't be a cold start. I always called the function a few times right before my tests and executed all tests directly one after the other.

540 seconds would probably be enough, but I also want to ensure that the notifications should not be sent with a delay of several minutes.

The idea of ​​storing a batch number is a good one. That should solve my problem.
Thank you for your help and the very quick response.